# Doubt about 0-norm in Majda Bertozzi

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm studyind Majda Bertozzi book about vorticity and incompressible flow, and I don't know what's the 0 norm which appears in it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes $\lVert x\rVert_0=\lvert\lbrace k\,:\, x_k\ne 0\rbrace\rvert$, so for instance $\lVert (1,0,-5,3)\rVert_0=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first line of p. 89 says, $\|\cdot\|_0$ is the $L^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^N$. The $0$ makes sense when you check out p. 97, where this is generalised to Sobolev spaces of functions having derivatives up to order $m$ that are in $L^2$. $L^2$ is then the case $m=0$.